# Using QGIS to filter some levels on the Ordnance Survey boundaries data

Tags: qgis, mapbox, ordnance-survey, mapbox-gl

I am working on a full UK map and I need the postcode level 1 and 2 (areas and districts) and while I have gotten the postcode level 1 data, I need the postcode level 2 (postcode districts) data that I was having trouble getting but then I've found this link : https://osdatahub.os.uk/downloads/open/BoundaryLine?_ga=2.128386122.790220339.1648013090-306484485.1648013090

From here I can get the data that I need but the data consists of :

1. Civil parishes
2. Wards
3. Communities
4. **Districts**
5. Counties
6. Metropolitan districts
7. Unitary authorities
8. Parliamentary constituencies
9. Electoral divisions
10. London boroughs
11. Greater London authorities
12. Greater London authority assembly constituencies
13. European electoral regions
14. Welsh assembly constituencies
15. Welsh assembly electoral regions
16. Scottish parliamentary constituencies
17. Scottish parliamentary electoral regions

I only need Districts, so is there any way to filter it and get only the data that I need?

Comment: Included in the bdline_essh_gb.zip download(538MB) is a lot of data. Please specify exactly what you need. A screenshot of the Attribute Table Column Heading you need would help.

Comment: @Pointdump I only need postcode districts from it not that a lot of data so I was wondering if there is any way to extract that specific postcode districts data from the  whole bdline_essh_gb.zip download(538MB) file

Comment: Have you downloaded the 538MB zip? What's in it? Or is your question "How can I avoid *downloading* 538MB when I only need the data of a fraction of it?"?

Comment: those are administrative districts not post code districts

Comment: Also, I don't think these "Districts" are "Postcode Districts", but "Administrative DIstricts". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Districts_of_England Look elsewhere for postcode districts boundaries.